# you may not have a proper app for viewing this content error

Tags: android

I have made a program with Android Studio software.
The program runs easily on some phones, but on another phone, it displays the following error message.

> You may not have a proper app for viewing this content error

Why do you think this error occurs on some phones and what part of the program should I check? 
`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.loridictionary.ir.loridictionary">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo3"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashPage">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Wellcome" />
        <activity android:name=".Register_Or_Enter" />
        <activity android:name=".Get_Number" />
        <activity android:name=".Get_SMS" />
        <activity android:name=".Register_Page" />
        <activity android:name=".Home_Page" />
        <activity android:name=".Maker" />
        <activity android:name=".About" />
        <activity android:name=".List" />
        <activity android:name=".ddword"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have used the Sqllite database in the program
For example :

```
package com.loridictionary.ir.loridictionary;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class SqlliteOpenhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static  final  String Database_name="ir.mosayebtorabi.LoriDic";
    public static  final  String words="words";
    public SqlliteOpenhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Database_name, null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + words + " (id STRING," +
                "telephone STRING,Words STRING,Meaning STRING,data STRING,deletee STRING)");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("delete from "+ words );
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean insert_information(String id,String telephone,String Words,String Meaning,String data,String deletee){
        SQLiteDatabase sql=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("id",id);
        contentValues.put("telephone",telephone);
        contentValues.put("Words",Words);
        contentValues.put("Meaning",Meaning);
        contentValues.put("data",data);
        contentValues.put("deletee",deletee);
        long chek=sql.insert(words,null,contentValues);
        if (chek==-1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    List<Datamysqllitee> getpost(Context context)
    {
        final List<Datamysqllitee> datamysqllites=new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase sql=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=sql.rawQuery("select * from "+ words,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                Datamysqllitee data=new Datamysqllitee();
                data.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                data.setTelephone(cursor.getString(1));
                data.setWords(cursor.getString(2));
                data.setMeaning(cursor.getString(3));
                data.setData(cursor.getString(4));
                data.setDeletee(cursor.getString(5));
                datamysqllites.add(data);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }else{
            if (Global.this_page.equals("List")){
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final ProgressBar wait=(ProgressBar)((com.loridictionary.ir.loridictionary.List)context).findViewById(R.id.wait);
            wait.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        }
        return datamysqllites;
    }
    public Integer deleteData (String telephone){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(words,"telephone = ?",new String[]{telephone});
    }
}
```

please help...

Comment: Check you minSdk in gradle file

Comment: please explain more

Answer (score 1):

When I try to install an .apk file from Whatsapp, I get the same error. and i found solutions like this.

1. Launch the File Manager app on your device.
2. Go whare your .apk file is exist [eg. storage/emulated/0/..]
3. Tap on the .apk file and follow the on-screen instructions to install it on your device.

> Its work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

> There are two API level settings available:
>   minSdkVersion — The minimum version of the Android platform on which the app will run, specified by the platform's API level identifier.
>
> targetSdkVersion — Specifies the API level on which the app is designed to run. In some cases, this allows the app to use manifest elements or behaviors defined in the target API level, rather than being restricted to using only those defined for the minimum API level.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone comes here for a solution:
This usually happens when you try to setup your APK from another application like: (Messenger, whatsapp,... etc.).
All you have to is:

- Make sure that the APK file is not corrupted as sometimes messaging apps compress those files so it corrupts
- Search for your APK File in (Files Manager) then install it from there NOT from the Chat message and it work properly